# Laravel hasManythrough?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship, has-many-through, has-many

I have three models creating a many-to-many relationship

```
ModelA(id)
ModelB(A.id,C.id)
ModelC(id,name)
```

How to fetch `C.name` using model `A`?

Currently model `A` hasOne model `B`, and model `C` hasMany model `B`. I tried to relate model `A` and `C` using `hasOnethrough` using model `B` but it gives me `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function myFunction()
{
    return $this->hasOnethrough(ModelC::class, ModelB::class,
        'a_id', 'id', 'id', 'c_id');
}
```

Based on your question `ModelB` is your pivot model to handle your relationship.

Normally we use pivot tables for many-to-many relationships, in that case you can use the `hasManyThrough` method.

You can try the above function in your `ModelA` model like you asked and will link to `modelC` through the `ModelB`

Then you can fetch it like a normal relationship output.